# Vanilla JavaScript img SlideShow w/ Btn, loading img slow

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

I have created an image slideshow with buttons using vanilla JavaScript. The images are loading fast when I have used the buttons for a while and load all the images. 
But when I reload the page and try to load the images using the buttons they load really slow at first. 
Is there any way to fix this?

Here's the HTML and JS

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <img src="img/img1.jpeg" id="slides">
  <button class="btn" id="previous">&#10094;</button>
  <button class="btn" id="next">&#10095;</button>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</div>
```

**Vanilla JavaScript**

```
var i = 0;
var images = [];

images[0] = "img/img1.jpeg";
images[1] = "img/img2.jpeg";
images[2] = "img/img3.jpeg";
images[3] = "img/img4.jpeg";

var nextImage = function () {
  if (i < images.length-1) {
    i++;
  } else {
    i = 0;
  }
  document.querySelector('#slides').src = images[i];
}

var previousImage = function () {
  if (i > 0) {
    i--;
  } else {
    i = images.length - 1;
  }
  document.querySelector('#slides').src = images[i];
}

  document.querySelector('#next').addEventListener('click', nextImage);
  document.querySelector('#previous').addEventListener('click', 
  previousImage);
```

First question for me on this site, sorry if I have formulated me wrong.

Comment: Probably server hosting the image URLs there is too slow - not a JS issue

Comment: Optimize your images.

Answer (score 0):

Optimize your images to a smaller size by changing the size of the image itself or the file type. This will decrease the time it takes to load.

Also, you can use Javascript to preemptively load the images. If there are a lot of images then you can have it load the adjacent ones in the slideshow.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your images have too much resolution than you need. If you are running this on a normal computer(or a mobile), you could have an image size around 250 pixels. Optimise your images by jpeg compression and by reducing the resolution of the image.

Read more from [here](https://kinsta.com/blog/optimize-images-for-web/)..